# ¿como contar secuencias de números iguales en matlab?

Tags: matlab

Tengo un problema para resolver en matlab en el cual tengo una secuencia de números binarios  por ejemplo `1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1` y el problema es que tengo que hacer un algoritmo que me cuente las veces que se repite un dígito pero consecutivos por ejemplo 1 una vez cero una vez, después 1 tres veces, cero 2 veces y el resultado se sume todos los que salieron de una vez, todos los que salieron 2 veces, todos los que salieron tres veces consecutivas

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: `Corridas=unique(sec); %donde sec es la secuencia de numeros
  
ocurrencias=zeros(numel(Corridas),1); 

for i=1:numel(Corridas) 

mask=sec==Corridas(i); 

ocurrencias(i)=nnz(mask); 

end `

pero lo único que logre fue que me diera el numero que se repiten los 1 y los ceros pero en total en toda la secuencia

Comment: Puedes pulsar en [edit] y añadir el código que tienes a la pregunta, en lugar de poner un comentario

Answer (score 0):

Tiene muchos años que no programo en matlab, así que espero poder guiarte.

La estrategia que yo usaría es usar un [map](/questions/tagged/map), como dicha estructura de datos no existe en [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) saría un arreglo para las claves y otro para los valores.

```
distintos = unique(secuencia) % llaves
cuenta = zeros(elementos,1) % valores
```

en el arreglo de la secuencia para poder comparar una posición con las subsecuentes lo haría a fuerza bruta mediante la comparación de un elemento secuencia<sub>i</sub> con uno secuencia<sub>j</sub> donde j inicia siempre en i+1 y va aumentando su valor mientras secuencia<sub>j</sub> sea igual que secuencia<sub>i</sub>, si secuencia<sub>j</sub> no fuera igual incrementaría secuencia<sub>i</sub>.

Supongo que s epuede optimizar para evitar casos, pero de momento no se me ocurre como.

Bueno para cada vez que se realice ese proceso lo que haría sería almacenar en una variable `maxconsecutivos` la subsecuencia más grande en el mapa si y solo sí es más grande que el valor que contenga ya el mapa.

Como verás debido a que estamos comparando pares de elementos, la secuencia más pequeña no puede ser menor a 1, por lo que siempre iniciamos `maxconsecutivos` en uno.

Para el caso de la primer iteración manejaría el caso aparte usando un centinela para guardar el valor actual o secuencia<sub>i</sub>.

Y en código quedaría algo así.

```matlab
secuencia = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
distintos = unique(secuencia)
elementos = numel(distintos)
elementossecuencia = numel(secuencia)
cuenta = zeros(elementos,1); 

maxconsecutivos = 1
valoractual = -1 % centinela
for i = 1 : (elementossecuencia-1)
  i
  if( valoractual == -1 )
    valoractual = secuencia(i)
  end
  for j = 2 : elementossecuencia
   j
    valorsiguiente = secuencia(j)
    if( valoractual == valorsiguiente)
      maxconsecutivos = maxconsecutivos + 1
    else
      idx = find(distintos == valoractual)
      savedmax = cuenta(idx)
      if(savedmax < maxconsecutivos)
        cuenta(idx) = maxconsecutivos
      end
      valoractual = valorsiguiente
      maxconsecutivos = 1
   end
  end  
end
```

Puedes verlo corriendo en [octave online](https://octave-online.net/bucket~XvDsEwwskpRwJKwTFYs6i3).